# Sum of two signed measures is well defined iff both do not take the same sign of $\pm \infty$

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and $\mu$  and $\nu$ be a signed measures on $(X,\mathcal{A})$. We say that $\lambda =\mu+\nu$ is well-defined as a function
$\lambda \: \mathcal{A} \to \overline {\mathbb R}$ given by
$\lambda (A) := \mu(A)+\nu(A) \quad \text{for $A\in \mathcal{A}$}$ if the latter sum always makes sense, i.e., iff $\{\mu(A),\nu(A)\}\ne \{-\infty, +\infty\}$ for all  $A\in \mathcal{A}$.

Show that $\lambda =\mu+\nu$ is well-defined if and only if both $\mu$ and $\nu$
do not take the value $-\infty$ or both do not take the value $+\infty$. Show that in this case $\lambda: \mathcal{A} \to \overline {\mathbb R}$ is a signed measure.

I have proven the backward implication, and I am having difficulty proving the backward case. Suppose $\mu$ takes $\infty$ and $\nu$ takes $-\infty$, for example. Then $\mu(A) = \infty$ and $\nu(B) = -\infty$ for some $A, B \in \mathcal A$. We want to find some $C \in \mathcal A$ such that $\{ \mu(C), \nu(C) \} = \{ \infty, -\infty \}$. I am not sure how I can find such a $C$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mu(A)=+\infty\implies\mu(X)=+\infty\quad$ and $\quad\nu(B)=-\infty\implies\nu(X)=-\infty$.

So just take $C=X$.

EDIT : for clarity I add some details (essentially what geetha290krm already wrote as a comment below). By definition of a signed measure, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint measurable sets, then $\mu(A)+\mu(B)$ is well-defined and equal to $\mu(A\cup B)$. Therefore, if $\mu(A)=+\infty$, then $\mu(A)+\mu(A^\complement)$ must be well-defined, which implies that $\mu(A^\complement)\neq-\infty$. Hence $\mu(A)+\mu(A^\complement)=+\infty=\mu(A\cup A^\complement)=\mu(X)$. A similar argument holds to show that $\nu(B)=-\infty\implies \nu(X)=-\infty$.

Comment: Of course. Did you downvote my answer? Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote your answer, I am not sure who. Thank you for your answer, I am looking into it now

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask for more details if something is not clear.

Comment: @Will I am the culprit who downvoted your correct answer due to some silly mis-understanding. I cannot upvote it now unless the answer is edited. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @Will yes, could you please clarify how $\mu(A) = \infty$ implies $\mu(X) = \infty$? I am assuming that a similar argument holds for $\nu(B) = - \infty \implies \nu(X) = - \infty$.

Comment: @Squirrel-Power $\mu (X)=\mu (A)+\mu (A^{c})=\infty+\mu (A^{c})$. By the definition of  a signed measure the second term cannot be $-\infty$. Hence, $\mu (X)=\infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks for the explanation. That can happen :)